# Laravel forget cache

Tags: laravel, caching

Laravel 8.0 CACHE_DRIVER=file.

Stored in cache 'posts' and 'post_detail'.

I'm using full url for save in cache unique page of pagination posts.

```
public function __contructor()
{

   $this->full_url = request()->fullUrl();        

}
```

// ALL POSTS WITH PAGINATION

```
public function posts()
{

   if (Cache::has("posts_".$this->full_url)) {

     $posts = Cache::get("posts_".$this->full_url);

    } else {

       $posts = Cache::rememberForever($this->full_url, function() {
                 return Post::paginate(15);
      });

   }

}
```

// DETAIL POST

```
public function post_detail($slug)
{

   if (Cache::has("post_detail_".$this->full_url)) {

     $post_detail = Cache::get("post_detail_".$this->full_url);

    } else {

       $post_detail = Cache::rememberForever("post_detail_".$this->full_url, function() {
                 return Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();
      });

   }

}
```

I can forget cache only for 'post_detail' but I have no idea how to remove the cache for all posts that include the key 'posts_'

// UPDATE POST

```
public function update() 
{
   ...
   $post->update();
   $full_url = $request->getSchemeAndHttpHost()."/".$post->post_categories->category_slug . "/" .$post->slug);
   Cache::forget("post_detail_".$full_url.""); // OK
   Cache::forget("posts_*"); // forget al posts contains 'posts_' key.
}
```

thanks

Comment: i feel like if you used a cached driver that supported tags this would become an easier problem to solve, perhaps